# Simulator turned Hello world

Tags: ios, swift, simulator

I'm learning Swift, using some objects.
but the simulator always turns white background and says hello world. 
[image]

Comment: ok ... so, what is wrong with "hello world" on white  background?

Answer (score 1):

You set the design in the LaunchScreen which actually should be in `Main.storyboard`

Search for a file called "Main.storyboard" and set the design there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your design in your `Launchscreen.storyboard`. This is only shown when your apps launches.

You **need** to create your design on `Main.storyboard` instead.